# BufferedReader readLine has null bytes unlike String() -- different encoding?

Tags: character-encoding, bufferedreader

In the following I'm trying to get some parts of a line printed, however I'm getting alternating null characters ONLY from the Strings that are from the input file.

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream( cmdLnArgs[0] )));
String s;
while ( (s = br.readLine()) != null ) {
    String[] columns = s.split( "\t" );
    String out = "/storage/37C4-1314/Music/" + columns[1] + "/" + columns[3] + "\n";
    System.out.print( out );
}
```

Why is the following happening?... [in fact I cannot copy/paste because of the nulls!]:

> /storage/37C4-1314/Music/ S a m e O l e L o v e . m p 3

i.e.:

[image]

Even "`+ new String(columns[3].getBytes("UTF-8"),"UTF-8")`" doesn't work for me.  Nor does [this](https://self-learning-java-tutorial.blogspot.com/2020/02/convert-utf-16-unicode-characters-to.html).

Comment: It appears that `FileInputStream` gets bytes in _Unicode_ (UTF-16)?

Comment: @JosefZ -- I believe you are correct, and perhaps I could go through "the contortion" of decoding into UTF-8, but I'm hoping for an easier way of reading lines from a txt file and then writing subsets back out (into a txt file ending in .m3u, as I'm translating a playlist from iTunes to a list for my Android)

Answer (score 1):

The following worked finally after trying SOOO many combinations:

```
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream( cmdLnArgs[0] );
    InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream( new File(cmdLnArgs[0]) ), "UTF-16");
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader( isr );
```